# WordPress how to override function adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head() in link-template.php the correct way

Tags: theme-development, customization, pluggable

I'm quite new to WordPress development. I'm using WordPress 4.9.2. I'm currently working on the following issue. I have several blog categories which have no relation to each other. For example "Our Services" and "News". Now I want to make sure that the Prev/Next links on each post page are only pointing to Prev/Next within the same category. This should apply for links on the page and for rel links in the head section. I figured already that I JUST have to set the flag $in_same_term to true. For the links at the end of the post, I solved the problem already inside my theme by adding correct args. Only the rel links in the head section are not working like this.

**Needed change for header**

From

```
function adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head() {
    if ( ! is_single() || is_attachment() ) {
        return;
    }
    adjacent_posts_rel_link();
}
```

To

```
function adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head() {
    if ( ! is_single() || is_attachment() ) {
        return;
    }
    adjacent_posts_rel_link('%title', true); //TODO find a better way
}
```

I just don't want to touch a WordPress core file. Could anyone help and guide me through the correct process, please?

Answer (score 2):

`adjacent_posts_rel_link()` calls [`get_adjacent_post_rel_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post_rel_link/), which runs its return value through the [`{$adjacent}_post_rel_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/adjacent_post_rel_link/) filter. The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$adjacent`, refers to the type of adjacency, 'next' or 'previous'.

You can use that filter to change the output accordingly. Here's an example to change the second parameter:

```
add_filter( 'next_post_rel_link', function( $link ) {
  return get_adjaxent_post_rel_link( '%title', true, '', false );
} );

add_filter( 'previous_post_rel_link', function( $link ) {
  return get_adjacent_post_rel_link( '%title', true );
} );
```

Comment: Thak you very much for your help but for me, this ends in an endless loop because get_adjaxent_post_rel_link is itself applying the filters. Do you have any other ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: @dj_thossi Ah, right. You'd need to run something like `remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ )` from inside the callback to prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: I tried the following at the beginning of single.php inside the theme and I still have an endless loop. may anyone be able to help?

    add_filter( 'previous_post_rel_link', function( $link ) {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
        return get_adjacent_post_rel_link( '%title', true, '', true );
   } );